# Declare variable within Javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. Recently I am trying to prepare a checkform function, although the function works, IE mentioned the "msg2" at the end was not declared, may experts please teach me how to make it work? Thanks a lot!

```
function check_si_form_info(form,mark,edit){
     if(mark==11 || mark=="all"){
            if(form.login.value==""){
                si_check_login.innerHTML="Please enter Login Name!";
                si_check_login.style.height="auto";
                form.login.style.backgroundColor="#FFD5FF";
                return false;
            }else if (form.login.value!==""){ 
            var loginname = form.login.value;
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('get','si/check_si_loginname.php?loginname='+loginname,true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                    if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        msg2 = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if(msg2 == '2'){
                        si_check_login.innerHTML="Login name is not available!";
                        si_check_login.style.height="auto";
                        form.login.style.backgroundColor="#FFD5FF";
                        return false;
                        }else if(msg2 == '1'){
                        si_check_login.innerHTML="";
                        si_check_login.style.height="0px";
                        form.login.style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
                        }
                    }//200
                }//4            
            }//onreadystatechange
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
            if (msg2 == '2'){
            return false;
            }
    }//11
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To declare a variable, add `var msg2;` at the beginning of your Currently, when your end of the function's body has reached, `msg2` is not yet defined. Also, you should declare all variables (`xmlhttp`) using `var`, unless you want them to leak to the global scope.

A variable can be defined in some ways:

- `var msg2;` inside the function: This DECLARES a private variable, and initialised it at `undefined`
- `var msg2;` outside the function: Declares a variable. Private if the inner function is contained within another scope, eg `function outer(){var msg2;function inner(){...}}`. Public otherwise.
- `msg2=null;` anywhere: This ASSIGNS `null` to variable `msg2`. If it has been defined already, see the previous line. Else, it will be publicly defined.

Consider your code:

```
function check_si_form_info(form,mark,edit){
     var msg2;// <-- Declare a variable
     if(mark==11 || mark=="all"){
            if(form.login.value==""){
               ...
                return false;
            }else if (form.login.value!==""){ 
            var loginname = form.login.value;
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open('get','si/check_si_loginname.php?loginname='+loginname,true);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                    if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        msg2 = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if(msg2 == '2'){
                            ...
                            form.login.style.backgroundColor="#FFD5FF";
                            return false; // <--- false isn't received by any func
                        }else if(msg2 == '1'){
                            ...
                        }
                    }//200
                }//4            
            }//onreadystatechange
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            }
            if (msg2 == '2'){ //<---This condition is always false
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare the `msg2` as a global variable then only you access it outside of the function.

put this line before the function

```
var msg2 ="";
function check_si_form_info(form,mark,edit){
```